# Preg match html code with multilines

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to get part of code inside **< ins>** tag from source:

```
<some tags there and code there><ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:670px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9438155779940585"
     data-ad-slot="1115596158"></ins>bla bla there <tags></tags>
```

I googled and searched all stackoverflow for hours, use site https://regexr.com/ and cant do it!

I tried :

```
/<ins[.\s]*<\/ins>/ism

/<ins[.|\s]*<\/ins>/ism

/<ins(\w\d\s.)*<\/ins>/ism (i know thats is totally wrong, but i also tried many combos like this)
```

And all million other combinations. Nothing helps, please help!

Comment: <ins(.|\s)*<\/ins>

Comment: Do you mean the content between `<ins></ins>`, all the attributes of the `<ins>` element, or the "bla bla there" part?

Comment: regex is not the tool you want to parse html. Other similar questions have been asked before, notably: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1836940

Comment: Thanks for everyone, I understand, parsing HTML with regexp - bad idea. Thats why now I use https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM and its a great and fast solution for me! Also it isn't easy to make some changes, for example its not possible to delete all comment nodes without braking brain.

Answer (score 0):

To match everything **within** the `ins` tags you want to use:

```
<\s*ins[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*ins\s*>
```

Or if the tag will be `<ins>` always with no `id=''` etc etc ..  You can simply:

```
<ins>([^<]*)<\/ins>
```

This for example

```
<ins>
   This is
   A Match
</ins>
```

Would return

```
This is
A Match
```

Example on [REGEX 101](https://regex101.com/r/uhhX6M/1) with detailed explanation for matching `<ins id="whatever"></ins>`

Example on [REGEX 101](https://regex101.com/r/iI5j0g/1/) with detailed explanation for matching just `<ins></ins>`

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure which part you actually want to retrieve, so here is a selfsufficient test script that includes all I could imagine :).

```
<?php

$src = <<<SRC
<some tags there and code there><ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:670px;height:100px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9438155779940585"
     data-ad-slot="1115596158">ins_content</ins>in_between<tags></tags></some>
SRC;

// What's inside <ins> and </ins>
$pattern = '@<ins[^>]*>(.*)</ins>@ium';
preg_match($pattern, $src, $matches);
echo $matches[1].PHP_EOL; // ins_content

// All attribues of the <ins> element
$pattern = '@(<ins([^>]+))@ium';
preg_match($pattern, $src, $matches);
echo $matches[2].PHP_EOL; // class="adsbygoogle" style...

// Everything between </ins> and <tags>
$pattern = '@ins>(.*)<tags@ium';
preg_match($pattern, $src, $matches);
echo $matches[1].PHP_EOL; // in_between
```